# AVCaptureSession startRunning exc_bad_access iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an exc_bad_access crash when starting an AVCaptureSession:

```
        if captureSession.isRunning == false {
           captureSession.startRunning()
        }
```

Notice: It was working in Swift 2.2. I'm having this crash only after migration to Swift 3.
Any idea!

Comment: Not sure if this is related or not but without a better description of the error  you might need to add this -> `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) requires access to your camera to upload business cards.</string>` to your info.plist with the Swift 3 update. To access the users camera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YES! [zsteed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524415/zsteed)'s answer works

Add to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow us to scan documents and capture images.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @karnett & @zsteed mentioned I had to add the camera privacy description to **info.plist**

To add it to **info.plist** source code add those 2 lines:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow us to scan images for QRCode.</string>
```

Or add new string item in the Property list, the key should be

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

and the value will be your description when the user will be asked to give permission for camera. Same as the screenshot below:

[image]

This will let the system ask the user whether they allow us to use the camera.

Thank you